# Querying aggregates on subdocuments then grouping by field in parent document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a noob when it comes to Mongo and I've been struggling to wrap my head around how to fetch data in the following fashion. I have a collection of order documents that contain some data such as an `event_id` and a subcollection (if that's the term) of `issued_tickets`. `issued_tickets` contains one to many subdocuments that contain fields such as `name`, `date`, etc. What I am trying to do is fetch the number of each type of issued tickets for each `event_id` in the parent document. So I would be wanting to do a count on each `issued_tickets` grouped by `issued_tickets.name` and then that goes up to the parent which is then summed and grouped on the parent's `event_id`.

Can anyone help me accomplish this? I keep spinning myself out on trying groupings and projections still.

Here is a sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7335c1c666f000414f74a"),
    "event_id" : ObjectId("5cb54f966668a9719ef6a103"),
    "subtotal" : 3000,
    "service_fee" : 760,
    "processing_fee" : 143,
    "total" : 3903,
    "customer_id" : ObjectId("5ce7666c1c335f000414f747"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:57:17.524Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:57:17.524Z"),
    "ref" : "60d5fcf9-86c6-469b-b86b-315a9b55caca",
    "issued_tickets" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7335c1c335f000414f666"),
            "name" : "Tier 1",
            "stub_name" : "Tier 1",
            "price" : 1500,
            "base_fee" : 200,
            "perc_fee" : "0.12",
            "access_code" : "163a1b9ee98338a8a4288a1c87446665",
            "redeemed" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7335c1c335f0004146669"),
            "name" : "Tier 2",
            "stub_name" : "Tier 2",
            "price" : 1500,
            "base_fee" : 200,
            "perc_fee" : "0.12",
            "access_code" : "f50f262cd0bf1ec4ab36667c2a762446",
            "redeemed" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: May we know, what is the expected output?

Comment: @varman I would be looking for something like: event_id, issued_ticket.name, count of issued_ticket.names for each event_id in the order collection (there is only one provided in the above example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do aggregations like following

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group` to reconstruct the array. While regrouping by `eventId` and `issued_tickets.name`, we can count using `$sum`

Mongo script :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$issued_tickets"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$event_id",
        ticketName: "$issued_tickets.name"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      event_id: "$_id._id",
      ticketName: "$_id.ticketName",
      count: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fxaMMYrM8rj)**

Comment: thanks! that did it. I was not realizing I could get all the fields into the grouping _id. Appreciate it!

Comment: You said you are new to mongo, But mongo is so easy, don't give it up. When I stared also, it was difficult. If you work with mongo aggregation atleast one month, you will love it :D